Package stix with and without professionalfonts
Using \texttt{professionalfonts}, how can I put "2" equal to "$2$" (mathmode) just as in the absence of \texttt{professionalfonts}? Code is the following:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stix}  
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Not exactly equal with \texttt{professionalfonts}: ``2'' and ``$2$''.

\bigskip

Removing \texttt{professionalfonts} above $/$ turns to an upper ``.''

\bigskip

Mantaining \texttt{professionalfonts}, how can I put ``2'' equal to ``$2$'' (mathmode) just as in the absence of \texttt{professionalfonts}?  
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Please show a screenshot of what you mean with "upper ."

A picture was added. The upper dot appears for character "$/$" by running the code deleting \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} in the preamble.

You can keep using the professionalfonts and combine it with the mathastext package to get the same numbers in math mode you'd normally get in text:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stix2}  
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Not exactly equal with \texttt{professionalfonts}: ``2'' and ``$2$''.

\bigskip

Removing \texttt{professionalfonts} above $/$ turns to an upper ``.''

\bigskip

Mantaining \texttt{professionalfonts}, how can I put ``2'' equal to ``$2$'' (mathmode) just as in the absence of \texttt{professionalfonts}?  
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Yes, exactly. Thank you very much.
